# Simple question regarding the Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning, poisson-distribution

I'm just trying to wrap my head around the Poisson distribution to make it more intuitive and I'm struggling with one (seemingly) paradoxical example.

Say we have a rate of 4 events in a given time period, for instance, 4 accidents in 1 week. What is the probability of exactly 6 accidents happening in 2 1-week periods, which (assuming I'm correct) is akin to an average of exactly 3 accidents per 1-week period?

Here we get:

$$P(X = 3) = \frac{\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}}{x!} = \frac{4^3e^{-4}}{3!} \approx 0.1954 $$

But say we now calculate it the following way, by estimating an average of 8 accidents per 2-week period, given our original rate of 4 accidents per 1-week period, and calculate for the original requirement (exactly 6 accidents in a 2-week period):

Here we get:

$$P(X = 6) = \frac{\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}}{x!} = \frac{8^6e^{-8}}{6!} \approx 0.1221 $$

Why are these probabilities not the same? Something tells me the original assumption of breaking down 6 accidents per 2-week period into 3 accidents per week is faulty, but I'm not really sure why. I have a few ideas but I'd prefer it if someone with expertise in this area would clarify.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Why should those be equal? Should also say, your notation is misleading.  $X$ and $P$ refer to different things in the two lines.

Comment: Just as a general matter, if $p_n$ denotes the probability of having exactly $n$ accidents in one week (given an average of $4$), and $\phi_n$ denotes the probability of having exactly $n$ accidents in two weeks (with an average of $8$) then $\phi_6=p_0\times p_6+p_1\times p_5+\cdots +p_6\times p_0$.  That does not suggest that $\phi_6=p_3$.

Comment: For intuition, consider the same question for $k$ weeks.  That is, for $k\in \mathbb N$, look at the probability, $\psi_k$ that you see exactly $3k$ accidents in $k$ weeks (with an average of $4k$ over that period).  You should expect that $\psi_k\to 0$ as $k$ grows.  To be significantly below average in one short trial is perfectly likely, but to be below average systematically for a very long time is extremely improbable.  Thus it is hardly surprising that $\phi_2<p_2$.

Comment: The probability of 6 accidents in 2 weeks at a rate of 4 per week, i.e. a rate of 8 per 2 weeks, would give the same result as 6 accidents in 1 week at a rate of 8 per week.

Comment: @lulu You say my notation is misleading, how so? How should it be written?

Comment: In the first line,  $P$ refers to a Poisson distribution with mean $4$, and in the second,  the mean is $8$. The notation should reflect the difference.

Comment: I've never seen Poisson distribution equations explicitly state two parameters in the input, as the mean is sort of "implied", or most questions revolve around one single mean exclusive to that particular scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a simpler model to illustrate the flaw in the first line of reasoning.

Suppose you have a fair coin and decide to flip it $n = 4$ times.  What is the probability that you get exactly $2$ heads and $2$ tails?  This is just
$$\binom{4}{2} \frac{1}{2^4} = \frac{3}{8}.$$

Now what is the probability that, among the first two coin tosses, you get $1$ head and $1$ tail, and among the last two coin tosses, you again get $1$ head and $1$ tail?  This is $$\left(\binom{2}{1} \frac{1}{2^2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4}.$$

Why are these not equal?  Simply put, the second case does not count all of the outcomes in which $2$ heads and $2$ tails are possible:  for instance, the outcomes
$$\{HHTT, \; TTHH\}$$
are included in the former but not the latter.

By the same token, counting $3$ events in the first week and $3$ in the second week is not the same as counting $6$ events in a $2$-week period, because the former requires that $3$ events are observed in each week, whereas the latter can include such outcomes as $4$ events in the first week and $2$ in the second; or $0$ outcomes in the first week and $6$ in the second.

Therefore, if we really wanted to count the outcomes this way, we might define $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda = 8)$ to represent the random number of events observed in a $2$-week period, and $Y \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda = 4)$ be the random number of events in a $1$-week period.  Then
$$\Pr[X = 6] = \sum_{y=0}^6 \Pr[Y = y]\Pr[Y = 6-y].$$

And you can verify this numerically by calculating the sum with $$\Pr[Y = y] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^y}{y!} = e^{-4} \frac{4^y}{y!},$$

hence
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{y=0}^6 \Pr[Y = y]\Pr[Y = 6-y] &= \sum_{y=0}^6 e^{-4} \frac{4^y}{y!} e^{-4} \frac{4^{6-y}}{(6-y)!} \\
&= e^{-8} \sum_{y=0}^6 \frac{4^6}{y!(6-y)!} \\
&= e^{-8} \frac{4^6}{6!} \sum_{y=0}^6 \frac{6!}{y!(6-y)!} \\
&= e^{-8} \frac{4^6}{6!} (1 + 1)^6 \\
&= e^{-8} \frac{8^6}{6!} \\
&= \Pr[X = 6].
\end{align}$$

Comment: I believe your answer is exactly what I was looking for, but there are a few things which I would like to be cleared up just to make sure I've got the correct understanding cemented in my mind.

Comment: In your summation equation, I assume this means that to calculate the probability of 6 events in 2 week period, you are adding the probability of there being 0 events in week 1, and 6 events in week 2, then 1 event in week 1, 5 events in week 2, and so forth?

The only other part I'm not sure about is how the factorial part suddenly changes to $(1 + 1)^6$ (3rd to 4th line of the manipulation). I see that it comes to 64 (2^6) but how it became $(1 + 1)^6$...unless there's an identity I'm unaware of?

Comment: @DanielPodobinski That is correct.  I'm adding up every possible combination of the number of events in each week that add up to $6$ total events over a two-week period.  As for the simplification, it is an application of the binomial theorem:  $$(a+b)^n = \sum_{y=0}^n \binom{n}{y} a^y b^{n-y},$$ with the choice $n = 6$ and $a = b = 1$, recalling that $\frac{6!}{y! \, (6-y)!} = \binom{6}{y}$.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, should have realised that we were only looking at the binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a Poisson process $X(t)$ with $\lambda =4$ then $P(X(t)=k)=\frac{(\lambda t)^k e^{-\lambda t}}{k!}$. Therefore the second result is correct. $P(X(2)=6)=\frac{(4\cdot 2)^6 e^{-4\cdot 2}}{6!}$.